System audio level intermittendly gets set to about 40%
I just moved from windows so im a bit of a noob but enjoying it so far.  Every so often i will go to do something like watch a vide or play a game and i will notice my volume is really low.  i got to the volume slider in the top right corner and it is setting around 40 percent or so.  Its not a huge deal but i mean, kind of a PITA.  I havent done too much since installation.  I assume its something to do with firefox?  no idea.
I am using the onboard sound card from my gigabyte mobo.
Gigabyte X570 GAMING X
Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Might just be a noob question but I dont like when things happen outside of my control. lol
